# Why does not work library dht11 for Arduino in Launchpad msp430 (g2553)?

Tags: arduino, msp430

Why does not work library, if the Launchpad is compatible with Arduino?
The sensor data is sufficient to derive to serial port.

What is the difference between dht11 and dht22 libraries?

Comment: the launchpad and arduino are two completely different architectures, they are not compatible with each other in any way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called [Energia](http://energia.nu) which says it's a fork of Arduino for the MSP430.

Alternatively there's a post [here](http://forum.43oh.com/topic/1825-interfacing-with-dht11-humidty-temp-sensor/#entry17355) with code to read the DHT11 on the MSP430 (native code, not using Energia, as far as I can tell), and another one [here](http://forum.43oh.com/topic/2239-solved-dht22-temp-rh-one-wire-sensor-on-energia/) with code to read the similar DHT22 on MSP430/Energia.

I understand from discussion about these sensors on the Picaxe forum that they're a bit picky about timing, so you may need some tinkering to get this stuff to work.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this while searching for DHT11 and MSP430, if the question is still valid:

Please check the following code(s) that I've written for interfacing DHT11 sensor and MSP430, the codes do not require any library, you can just paste it in your main.c file in code composer studio and debug+resume. 1st file below(dht11_MSP430G2553) does a one time read and you can see the values in the expressions window, the second file (MSP430_DHT11_Sensor) is more mature and it reads the values in a loop by resetting the microcontroller with watchdog timer and it outputs the values to the serial monitor in 19200 baud
https://github.com/selimg76/microcontroller/blob/master/dht11_MSP430G2553
https://github.com/selimg76/microcontroller/blob/master/MSP430_DHT11_Sensor

Detailed explanations are in the following videos:

https://youtu.be/Hid_jB_Dy-A
https://youtu.be/Fzf8q6fgxfQ